# How to transform part of an api response to full json in python

Tags: python, json, python-3.x, string, api

I have managed to get my data back out of a system, but one of the fields is coming back as a long string of pipe-delimited data, instead of json format.

This is the api call and response handling from my python script:

```
        info = requests.request("GET", url, headers=headers, verify=False)
        data = info.json()

        return(data)
```

This is a sanitized version of the response data. The field that I'm concerned with is the data within the "properties" field. How can I transform this to a nested json array?

```
[
    {
        "id": 00000001,
        "name": "hostname1",
        "type": "HostRecord",
        "properties": "absoluteName=hostname1.mydomain.com|parentId=00000010|parentType=Zone|reverseRecord=false|addresses=10.10.10.11|addressIds=00000100|"
    },
    {
        "id": 00000002,
        "name": "hostname2",
        "type": "HostRecord",
        "properties": "absoluteName=hostname2.mydomain.com|parentId=00000020|parentType=Zone|reverseRecord=true|addresses=10.10.10.12|addressIds=00000200|"
    }
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

something like the below

```
data = [
    {
        "id": "00000001",
        "name": "hostname1",
        "type": "HostRecord",
        "properties": "absoluteName=hostname1.mydomain.com|parentId=00000010|parentType=Zone|reverseRecord=false|addresses=10.10.10.11|addressIds=00000100|"
    },
    {
        "id": "00000002",
        "name": "hostname2",
        "type": "HostRecord",
        "properties": "absoluteName=hostname2.mydomain.com|parentId=00000020|parentType=Zone|reverseRecord=true|addresses=10.10.10.12|addressIds=00000200|"
    }
]


def make_dict(properties: str) -> dict:
    result = {}
    pairs = properties.split('|')
    for pair in pairs:
        if pair:
            k, v = pair.split('=')
            result[k] = v
    return result


for entry in data:
    entry['properties'] = make_dict(entry['properties'])
print(data)
```

output

```
[{'id': '00000001', 'name': 'hostname1', 'type': 'HostRecord', 'properties': {'absoluteName': 'hostname1.mydomain.com', 'parentId': '00000010', 'parentType': 'Zone', 'reverseRecord': 'false', 'addresses': '10.10.10.11', 'addressIds': '00000100'}}, {'id': '00000002', 'name': 'hostname2', 'type': 'HostRecord', 'properties': {'absoluteName': 'hostname2.mydomain.com', 'parentId': '00000020', 'parentType': 'Zone', 'reverseRecord': 'true', 'addresses': '10.10.10.12', 'addressIds': '00000200'}}]
```

Answer (score 1):

Try this out:

```
a = [
{
    "id": 1,
    "name": "hostname1",
    "type": "HostRecord",
    "properties":"absoluteName=hostname1.mydomain.com|parentId=00000010|parentType=Zone|reverseRecord=false|addresses=10.10.10.11|addressIds=00000100|",
},
{
    "id": 2,
    "name": "hostname2",
    "type": "HostRecord",
    "properties": "absoluteName=hostname2.mydomain.com|parentId=00000020|parentType=Zone|reverseRecord=true|addresses=10.10.10.12|addressIds=00000200|",
},
]

for list_item in a:
    temp_dict = {}
    for item in list_item["properties"].split("|"):
        if item != "":
            key1, value1 = item.split("=")
            temp_dict[key1] = value1
    list_item["properties"] = temp_dict

print(a)
```

Output:

```
[{'id': 1, 'name': 'hostname1', 'type': 'HostRecord', 'properties': {'absoluteName': 'hostname1.mydomain.com', 'parentId': '00000010', 'parentType': 'Zone', 'reverseRecord': 'false', 'addresses': '10.10.10.11', 'addressIds': '00000100'}}, {'id': 2, 'name': 'hostname2', 'type': 'HostRecord', 
'properties': {'absoluteName': 'hostname2.mydomain.com', 'parentId': '00000020', 'parentType': 'Zone', 'reverseRecord': 'true', 'addresses': '10.10.10.12', 'addressIds': '00000200'}}]
```

Answer (score 0):

If I'm understanding correctly, you want `"absoluteName=hostname1.mydomain.com|parentId=00000010"` to turn into the array `["absoluteName=hostname1.mydomain.com", "parentId=00000010"]`. If that is the case, your solution is pretty simple:

```
for dct in data:
    dct['properties'] = dct['properties'].split('|')
```

This just splits the string at `'|'`, returning the resulting list and setting it equal to the `properties` field again.

But, I'm not sure that's exactly what you're looking for. Is that what you meant by "nested json array"?